# Fitting numerical data in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, seaborn, libraries

I have more than 100,000 numbers to analyze in Python. Part of it is given in this sample: 84.49, 60.885, 33.6, 0, 6.4, 89.361, 0, 0, 5.6, 0, 39.828.

The sum of this sample is 320.164 and I want to scale so that the new figures add up to 500 and plot these values.

I previously divided my desired sum (500) by the old sum (320.164) and multiplied each value. The 0 values remain 0 since 0 cannot be "scaled". Is there a way to do this in Python? And will it be possible to plot the new histogram/distribution?
Can you give some examples?

Comment: Can you please provide a minimum working example of what you have so far?
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot  as plt
numbers = [84.49, 60.885, 33.6, 0, 6.4, 89.361, 0, 0, 5.6, 0, 39.828]
current_sum = np.sum(numbers)
desired_sum = 500

new_numbers = [desired_sum/current_sum * x for x in numbers]
plt.hist(new_numbers)
```